# Why is the end of an iteration realized with a StopIteration Exception

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, iterator

When looking at Stackoverflow-Questions about when to raise Exceptions and when to simply return `None` in Python functions, the emerging picture is that you should use Exceptions for unexpected behaviour and return `None` otherwise.

However, for-loops over iterables are realized via the `StopIteration` Exception raised by the `next()` method, although eventually reaching the "end" of an iterable usually isn't unexpected. Why is the for-loop over iterables implemented the way it is?

Comment: For loop over iterators/generators, not just iterables. All Iterators are iterable, but the reverse is not always true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The overall answer is you cannot use sentinel values to safely state the end of an iterator/generator. Imagine simply that you have a list of `None` objects, `None` can no longer be used as a sentinel value. That's why `StopIteration` is used: no sentinel value, the problem is avoided.

If you want to avoid this behavior and return a default value in `next`, you can simply call `next(generator, None)`.

Comment: More so, it is probably easier to simply propagate an error in the case of nested generators that use the `yield from` syntax, to signal exhaustion of the source generator.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: `yield from` didn't exist when the decision to use `StopIteration` was made, though. Heck, generators didn't exist at all at the time.

Comment: Also, `yield from` doesn't propagate `StopIteration`. It catches the exception and uses the exception's `value` as the value of the `yield from` expression.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for clearing that up. Had to go back to read the [formal semantics](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/#formal-semantics) of the `yield from` syntax. I think the error is still indirectly propagated tho, since a StopIteration in a sub-generator triggers a `StopIterator` in the delegate.